# Assign Existing group to Folder in document library CSOM C#

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions, csom, folder

I am working with SharePoint 2010.

I am trying to assign existing group to the folder in `Document Library` using `Client Side Object Model C#`.

I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85703/grant-permissions-to-list-items-using-existing-sharepoint-group-using-client-obj/85706#85706) code in answer. This works but it ask for `RoleType` and I don't want to specify any `RoleType`.

I just want to assign the group permission to my folder in `Document Library` without specifying `RoleType` externally because I want to assign the existing permission of group to folder.

So I need help for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of answer by [@Ankit Kumar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/49849/ankit-kumar), I tried the code given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167104/assign-unique-permission-to-sharepoint-2013-list-using-client-side-code-c/167109#167109). But his code is for SharePoint 2013. And the question is for SharePoint 2010.

In SharePoint 2010 `var GRoup1 = cpx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);` will always gives error

> Method "GetByName" does not exist.

So I modified the code to get the group name as shown below:

```
Group grp = null;
GroupCollection groupColl = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
clientContext.Load(groupColl,
    groups => groups.Include(
    group => group.Title,
    group => group.Id));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Group siteGroup in groupColl)
{
    if (siteGroup.Title.Equals("TestGroup"))
    {
        grp = siteGroup;
        break;
    }
}
```

And after that using following code I was able to implement this on my SharePoint 2010 Environment.

```
var roletypes = clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
listItemObject.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(roletypes);
listItemObject.RoleAssignments.Add(grp, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
listItemObject.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Where `listItemObject` is your folder context. This code worked for me at my 2010 Environment.

Let me know if this solved your problem or any further help needed.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are not trying to break the inheritance. Did you try by keeping folder.BreakInheritance as false.or if you exclude this line :

```
collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader)); //Set permission type
```

Also check this. here if you pass role types as null.
[Assign Unique permission to SharePoint 2013 List using Client Side code C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167104/assign-unique-permission-to-sharepoint-2013-list-using-client-side-code-c/167109#167109)

Comment: I am already able to use this code properly, But the group already have the permission, So I don't want to specify the role type. I just want to assign the group without specifying the role type. Is it possible?

Comment: yeah thats mean u r going to inherit the permission from parent. Thats what I have asked you to check above.

Comment: I need for 2010. I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client of version v14.